# Fetch summoner name from id

Tags: java, riot-games-api

I am currently using the java-version of the Riot api, made by rithms,
(https://github.com/rithms/riot-api-java)
and I am trying to receive the name of a champion, as I am currently "just" able to get the id.

```
RankedStats rankedStats = api.getRankedStats(api.getSummonerByName("AscendedKitten").getId());
```

Now, when printing out the results of

```
rankedStats.getChampions();
```

it will (of course) return the Ids.
I noticed that

```
net.rithms.riot.dto.Champion.Champion
```

has a methode returning the name, but (because I am failing at reading the Documentation) I haven't found out how to cast / get an instance of the object yet.

I am sorry for the basic-question, and I hope you don't have too much trouble trying to help me :3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into this class. [Champion.java](https://github.com/rithms/riot-api-java/blob/master/src/net/rithms/riot/dto/Static/Champion.java)

Comment: I've already looked into this class, but found no way to cast something (for example a champion from  the champion-list, in a for loop) to riot.dto.Static.Champion

Comment: use the [static api](https://github.com/rithms/riot-api-java/blob/master/src/net/rithms/riot/api/StaticDataApi.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RiotApi class' getDataChampion(Region region, int id) method, then use the getName() method on the champion it returns.